# Getting the Physical Device Object for a specific volume id

Tags: windows, kernel, setupapi, drives

I want to query different flags of a specific volume. Input should be the volume id, for instance:

`\\?\Volume{b1a245f3-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\`,

then some flags are checked and the output is true/false depending if the desired flags are set.

The question is: How can I retrieve the Physical Device Object for a specific volume id? Exists there a method which takes the volume id as input or do I have to enumerate over all device objects?